# jQuery horizontal list slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I've created the following list slider: http://jsfiddle.net/XNBMr/5/

I want the "blue" element to be "slide-able". Currently I can only change between the options by clicking on each separate LI.

I want this to slide when the "blue" is selected and moved left or right.

I'm hoping this will be possible, as I want it to work on touch screens.

Comment: It is possible as I've seen it before (http://lsr.ca/en/about/#chrono) but it's not a walk in the park. I can't help with the code but maybe the site will teach you something!

Comment: Damn! @ComputerArts was faster...

Comment: Thanks @ComputerArts I'll have a look into that website. A drag and drop is what I require.